# Can one create an ARFaceGeometry instance with raw vertices instead of blendShapes, like ARSession does when run with ARFaceTrackingConfiguration?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

ARFaceGeometry has an initialization method for an array of blendShapes, but how would one create this object with an array of ARFaceGeometry vertices?

In Apple's [Creating Face-Based AR Experiences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences) the ViewController is passed an ARFaceTrackingConfiguration instance and so the ARSession appears to create an ARFaceAnchor instance and keep it updated with the face tracked by the TrueDepth Camera. This can be clearly seen in the ARSession's delegate's renderer method `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` in the VirtualContentUpdater.

As this ARAnchor's ARFaceGeometry is successfully updating to match the current state of the face via `virtualFaceNode?.update(withFaceAnchor: faceAnchor)` in VirtualContentUpdater and through `faceGeometry.update(from: anchor.geometry)` in the case of the Mask as the geometry, it must be true that somewhere behind the scenes an ARFaceGeometry instance is getting created or updated from higher resolution data (TD Camera) than blendShapes provide.

Do you know how this is occurring and how I might do this myself, and if not, do you know how I might find the code behind the scenes to dig through and discover how it's being done to use? Is utilizing such non-public parts of the iOS libraries viable?

Sorry, I'm extremely new to swift and the iOS development ecosystem, so I'm not sure where/how to even find the pertinent code, or if it's available. Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ARFaceGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry) has a `vertices` property and according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry)

> Only the vertices buffer changes between face meshes provided by an AR
>   session, indicating the change in vertex positions as ARKit adapts the
>   mesh to the shape and expression of the user's face.

In this case blend shape coefficients are *not* useful to you. When the delegation methods are called the `ARFaceGeometry` has already been mutated according the `ARFaceAnchor` internal state. How it's done is completely internal to ARKit and not publicly exposed.

The position of the vertices of the `ARFaceGeometry` are then just used to update the position of the vertices of the `ARSCNFaceGeometry` which is a subclass of [`SCNGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry).

Comment: I was hoping to serialize ARFaceGeometry and reconstruct it on the other side to update the position of ARSCNFaceGeometry vertices in an ARFaceAnchor. From what you've said it sounds like this is not possible with the full mesh as Apple does internally, only blendShapes like described in the discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnfacegeometry/2928196-update So, perhaps the only way to reconstruct the full face-mesh after serialization is to use the superclass SCNGeometry/SCNGeometrySource and construct something manually? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ultimately sync the state of faces between two devices across a network to create a real-time animated chat like https://www.animet.io/ which I was hoping could be done with ARKit, but it seems like it's probably not flexible enough alone and need to use SceneKit.

Comment: To be clear, can still use ARKit too, but it seems only for the local rendition of a face (top right like video chat), as once transmitted to the other device it doesn't seem possible to reconstruct with ARKit, but can be made as a SceneKit animation.

Comment: @Laser these “what I’m really trying to do” comments might be better incorporated into your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comments on @mnuages’ answer, it sounds like your question isn’t really about manipulating `ARSCNFaceGeometry` — it’s about the deeper issue of trying to send face geometry data obtained on one device over to another device and then render it (using SceneKit).

There are two good directions to look in for solving this issue:

#### Try blend shapes

You’ve assumed that transmitting blendShapes won’t give you the result you’re looking for, but have you tried it? In my experience, pulling the `faceGeometry` from an `ARFaceAnchor` versus pulling the anchor’s `blendShapes` and then using them to create a fresh `ARFaceGeometry` yield nearly the same result.

#### BYO Geometry

`ARSCNFaceGeometry` doesn’t have a way to be initialized from “raw” vertex data. But its superclass `SCNGeometry` does:

1. Beforehand, create `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement` instances for the parts of `ARFaceGeometry`’s data that the documentation notes are static: the `textureCoordinates` and `triangleIndices` buffers, respectively.
2. When you get a new face anchor from ARKit, create an `SCNGeometrySource` from its `vertices` data. Then create an `SCNGeometry` using that vertex source and the texture coordinate source and geometry element you made beforehand.
3. Set the new geometry on a node and you’re ready to render.

(There are probably more efficient ways to schlep this vertex data around in SceneKit, but this should be enough to get you to your first visible result, at least. Also, sorry... no code since I’m writing on iPad at the moment — but check the mentioned symbols in the docs and the rest should be clear.)

Comment: I have been trying & trying to do exactly this. But I have been unable to recreate a vertex source that then inherits the auto-resize & blendshape magic that the vertex source produced by Apple with ARSCNFaceGeometry(device:) does. This is simply not possible mate.

Comment: There’s no magic auto updating in `ARFaceGeometry` or `ARSCNFaceGeometry`. What magic there is comes from `ARSession` pushing you a new `ARFrame` every 1/60 s, where the frame’s `ARFaceAnchor` contains a new `ARFaceGeometry` matching the detected face *as of that frame*. If you create a vertex source with steps 1-3 in my answer, you just have one snapshot in time—to track and animate, you need to repeat those steps for every frame.